# Push en Schema de Mongoose . object dento

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Basicamente preciso saber cómp (si es posible). Dentro de los Schemas de mongoose, estoy armando una app para guardar tarifa (adr) y ocupacion (occ) de un hotel... por lo que preciso saber si es posible hacer schema dentro de otro schema, dentro de otro schema (esta parte la logré)...
Hotel.js

```
const Calendario = require('./Calendario');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const HotelSchema = new Schema({
    htl: {type: String, required: true},
    compset: [{c1: String, c2: String, c3: String, c4: String}],
    data: [Calendario.schema],
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Hotel', HotelSchema);
```

Calendario.js

```
const Day = require('./Day');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const CalendarioSchema = new Schema({
    20200401: [Day.schema],
    20200402: [Day.schema],
    20200403: [Day.schema],
    20200404: [Day.schema]
}];
module.exports = mongoose.model('Calendario', CalendarioSchema);
```

Day.js

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const DaySchema = new Schema({
    adr: {type: Number},
    occ: {type: Number}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Day', DaySchema);
```

lo que no logro hacer es guardar el "adr" y la "occ" con un push...

```
const router = express.Router();

const Hotel = require('../models/Hotel');
//const Calendario = require('../models/Calendario');
//const Day = require('../models/Day');


router.get('/extranet/add', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('extranet/new_hotel');
});
router.post('/extranet/new_hotel', (req, res) =>{
    const {htl, c1, c2, c3, c4, adr, occ}= req.body;
    //const test= [{adr, occ}];
    const errors = [];

    if(!htl){
        errors.push({text: 'Falta nombre del Hotel'});
    }
    if(!c1){
        errors.push({text: 'Falta nombre del Competidor 1'});
    }
    if(!c2){
        errors.push({text: 'Falta nombre del Competidor 2'});
    }
    if(!c3){
        errors.push({text: 'Falta nombre del Competidor 3'});
    }
    if(!c4){
        errors.push({text: 'Falta nombre del Competidor 4'});
    }
    if(!adr){
        errors.push({text: 'Falta ADR'});
    }
    if(!occ){
        errors.push({text: 'Falta OCC'});
    }
    if(errors.length > 0){
        res.render('extranet/new_hotel',{
            errors,
            htl,
            c1,
            c2,
            c3,
            c4,
            adr,
            occ
        });
    } else{
        const newHotel = new Hotel({htl, c1, c2, c3, c4, adr, occ});
        newHotel.compset.push({c1, c2, c3, c4});

        newHotel.data.20200401.push({adr, occ});
        console.log(newHotel);
        //console.log(test);

    res.send('Ok');
    }
});
router.get('/extranet/extranet', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('extranet/extranet');
});


module.exports = router;
```

el numero 20200401, lo modifique por una constante llamada "test" para evitar errores pero tampoco me funcionó>>>
Espero puedan ayudarme!

Comment: No logro comprender lo que quieres hacer. *Esquema dentro de Esquema*, eso hace que me estalle el cerebro. ¿Podrías indicar el tipo de documento que deseas almacenar en tu colección? ¿No te sirve usar referencias en vez de eso que tu llamas *esquema dentro de esquema*? ¿Porqué separar la lista de competidores en campos, no sería mejor una lista llamada *competidores* o algo por el estilo? ¿ *DaySchema* es un nombre apropiado para guardar un dato tipo *adr* y *occ*? ¿Porqué usar verbos de acciones en las rutas de tus *endpoints* (`/extranet/add`)? En fin tu pregunta me genera muchas dudas.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es indicar que un campo de tu schema principal es tipo otro  schema? 

**const { Schema } = mongoose;
const DaySchema = new Schema({
    adr: {type: adrSchema},
    occ: {type: occSchema}
});**

Comment: exactamente! pero creo que voy a tener que hacerlo en 2 instancias! es decir cuando ya este guardado en mongodb y retomarlo y guardar el objeto data....